# TERMUX- bash: ./a.out: Permission denied

Tags: android, bash, terminal, termux

[image]

Why do I keep getting this error?

```
>> gcc a.out
>> ./a.out
bash: ./a.out: Permission denied
```

I even tried this

```
>> chmod +x a.out
```

But still I keep getting the error. I have installed ***clang*** and ***termux-setup-storage*** package. My files are in main memory (not on sd card).

Termux has only problem executing **a.out** file. If I make any error in C program it fails to compile the **a.c** file

Comment: What does `ls -l a.out` give?

Comment: **ls -l a.out**  gives **-rw-rw---- 1 root everybody 8176 Dec 28 19:20 a.out**    
Looks like there is no **x**.

Comment: @KangkanLahkar: it's probably due to execute bit disabled on sdcard

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't execute executable in internel storage because that's mount with noexec in android.
Move that binary somewhere in termux home directory or $PREFIX.

Comment: `cat /proc/mounts | grep storage/emulated | grep noexec`, and there are lots of [symbinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61700922/how-does-the-android-system-create-the-storage-self-primary-directory).

Answer (score 0):

so if you need to run those file than you need to run
`$ ls`     //to see your file is here or not .if not than change directory
`$ mv a.out ~`
`$cd ~`
`$chmod +x a.out`
`$./a.out`

Answer (score 0):

If you just installed termux api?

```
$ pkg install root-repo
```

Revoke termux app permission in settings.

```
$ termux-setup-storage
```

And taraa!!