# Termux(rust) cargo run error: permission denied

Tags: rust, android-permissions, rust-cargo, permission-denied, termux

When im trying to use cargo build or cargo run it results error: permission denied 13. Here's [the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GIzb.jpg).

I already installed root-repo and gave storage access to termux, i also tried to use "chmod +x build-script-build" but nothing helped, my phone isn't rooted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TERMUX- bash: ./a.out: Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65478199/termux-bash-a-out-permission-denied)

Comment: Your project can't be in shared `storage`. Only app storage can be executed.